# opportunitycontactrole in salesforce triggers

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I'm working on an apex trigger and I keep getting errors in selecting 'contact'
I've tried a lot of different configurations of this sort of code and i just can't get it to work.
the forceide says there is no contact on opportunitycontactrole
i'm out of ideas.

Here is my code so far:

trigger add_primary_advisor on Opportunity(after insert, after update) {
List primaries=new List();

```
 for(Opportunity o:
    [Select Contact
    From OpportunityContactRole
    Where OpportunityContactRole='Staff' and isPrimary='True']) {

    primaries.add(Contact);
    }
    return primaries;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact is not a valid field on OpportunityContactRole

This Object stores only the reference to Contact as ContactId.

If you want to access Contact's fields from OpportunityContactRole  you can access by cross-refrencing to its fields as as below.

```
List<Contact> primaries = new List<Contact>();
for(Opportunity o:
    [Select Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Contact.Email
     From OpportunityContactRole
     Where OpportunityContactRole='Staff' and isPrimary='True']) {
   primaries.add(new Contact(FirstName=o.Contact.FristName, 
            LastName = o.Contact.LastName, Email =o.Contact.Email));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't supply the exact error I am going to assume the error is because you are attempting to add a non-existent variable "Contact" to your list "primaries". What you probably want to be adding is "o.Contact".

Answer (score 0):

Goto OpportunityContactRole, and check if Contact is there. May be it is Contact__C which is more likely.

The problem is with SOQL query for sure.